# Mongoose required validator fails value is undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I try to save data in a mongoose schema but the required validator fails, the error message says the value is undefined but the log before states it has a value.

I tried using new mongoose.Schema instead of new Schema but this diden't work as well.

When I remove the required tag it save but it is empty:
{ bookingNumber: { _id: 5d4b47d7685936130080eb70, __v: 0 } }

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const BookingNumberSchema = new Schema({
    number: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
});

const BookingNumber = mongoose.model('BookingNumber', BookingNumberSchema);

module.exports = BookingNumber;



function createBookingNumber(req, res){ 

    console.log(req.body);
    BookingNumber.create(req.body)
        .then(bookingNumber =>{
            let reply = {
                "bookingNumber": bookingNumber
            }
            res.status(200);
            console.log(reply);
            res.send(reply);
        })
        .catch(err =>{
            res.status(400);
            console.log(err);
            res.send(err);
        });
}
```

in my app.js I use bodyParser.json and filter for nosql attacks:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(filter());
```

Postman data:

```
{
    "bookingNumber": { 
        "number": 1,
        "description": "example bookingnumber"
    }
}
```

reply:

```
{
    "errors": {
        "description": {
            "message": "Path `description` is required.",
            "name": "ValidatorError",
            "properties": {
                "message": "Path `description` is required.",
                "type": "required",
                "path": "description"
            },
            "kind": "required",
            "path": "description"
        },
        "number": {
            "message": "Path `number` is required.",
            "name": "ValidatorError",
            "properties": {
                "message": "Path `number` is required.",
                "type": "required",
                "path": "number"
            },
            "kind": "required",
            "path": "number"
        }
    },
    "_message": "BookingNumber validation failed",
    "message": "BookingNumber validation failed: description: Path `description` is required., number: Path `number` is required.",
    "name": "ValidationError"
}
```

console.log:

```
{ bookingNumber: { number: 1, description: 'example bookingnumber' } }
{ ValidationError: BookingNumber validation failed: description: Path `description` is required., number: Path `number` is required.
        message: 'Path `description` is required.',
        name: 'ValidatorError',
        properties: [Object],
        kind: 'required',
        path: 'description',
        value: undefined,
        reason: undefined,
        [Symbol(mongoose:validatorError)]: true },
     number:
```

I looks like the input values don't get passed on to mongoose but I cant find why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the postman you sent data:

```
{
   "bookingNumber": { 
       "number": 1,
       "description": "example bookingnumber"
   }
}
```

and your schema BookingNumber there is no key like you sent "bookingNumber" with a nested object which mongoose validator checked no "number" and no "description" this is the reason your request failed.
 just only send it like:

```
{ 
   "number": 1,
   "description": "example bookingnumber"
}
```